# Solid not smooth using screw modifier

Tags: screw-modifier

I am importing an SVG shape and rotating it using the screw modifier.

I have applied the Shade Smooth on the two examples below.

[image]

On the left, the object is still a curve with the screw modifier, and on the right, it is converted to mesh.

On the mesh, I have checked that I have "Clear Seams" and "Clear Sharp" edges on edit mode, but I still have flat reflections.

---

The specific problem appears when I activate the Auto Smooth checkbox, so I get rid of the ridges of geometry on the left, regardless of the Auto Smooth angle (right).

[image]

Can you please tell me how to smooth this?

Here is the file: http://otake.com.mx/Foros/Blender/Bottle.blend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bezier version has its *Fill Mode* set to *Both*, it looks like when you convert it to mesh it creates inner faces that are connected to your outer faces (edges must not be connected to more than 2 faces) and that mess up your geometry, so switch it to *None*, convert, and it works fine. Also don't forget to recalculate the normals (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>).

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you, that worked :o)